# CIImage: set color of one specific pixel

Tags: ios9, ciimage

How can I set the color of one particular pixel of a `CIImage`? I need to have the most performant option to do this...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set just **one** pixel, you can create a small color kernel that compares a passed target coordinate with the current coordinate and colors the output appropriately. For example:

```
let kernel = CIColorKernel(string:
"kernel vec4 setPixelColorAtCoord(__sample pixel, vec2 targetCoord, vec4 targetColor)" +
    "{" +
    "   return int(targetCoord.x) == int(destCoord().x) && int(targetCoord.y) == int(destCoord().y) ? targetColor : pixel; " +
    "}"
)
```

Then, given an image, let's say a solid red:

```
let image = CIImage(color: CIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0))
    .imageByCroppingToRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 640))
```

If we want to set the pixel at 500, 100 to blue:

```
let targetCoord = CIVector(x: 500, y: 100)
let targetColor = CIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1)
```

The following will create a `CIImage` named `final` with a single blue pixel in a sea of red:

```
let args = [image, targetCoord, targetColor]
let final = kernel?.applyWithExtent(image.extent, arguments: args)
```

If you want to draw more than one pixel, this may not be the best solution though.

Simon